# Android: Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate

Tags: android, amazon-s3, download, kindle-fire

I have develop one android application, in which images and audio are download from Amazon S3 bucket. In all devices(sony xperia sola, HTC Salasa, Micromax funbook, samsung tab 2) and android emulator it download perfectly.

But When I try to download images and audio in kindle fire. It gives me Error like

```
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:332)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2781)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:872)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.Infoware.famouspeople.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:122)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:285)
04-01 03:58:01.148: W/System.err(15854):    ... 4 more
```

Can Any One help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What version of android support a kindle fire?

Comment: @Yahor10: I used kindle fire with version 2.3. Before few days it runs perfectly suddenly it gives this type of error

Comment: @Infoware is there https on the URL?

Comment: @Androyds: I am not using URL for download. I am using aws-android-sdk-1.4.0-debug.jar for downloading

Comment: Maybe aws-android-sdk-1.4.0-debug.jar  is not support your cert

Comment: @Yahor10: I have already used aws-android-sdk-1.3.0-debug.jar but same error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. It turned out it was caused by a transparent HTTP(S) proxy on the wifi router redirecting to a wifi login page. Might be worth checking this. The errors can appear intermittent if your authorization on the wifi network times out for example.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just change android version to 4.1 and resolve the problem. Please try in your code may be it will help you.